# Display various items in a div

Tags: html, css, alignment

i have made my design in figma for my course landing page.

My problem it's in the modules design.

The design:

[image]

The html i made is this:

```
<div class="modules">
                <div>
                    <p>Módulo 1</p>
                    <div class="spacer"></div> 
                    <p>Enquadramento operacional da cibersegurança</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Módulo 2</p>
                    <div class="spacer"></div> 
                    <p>Fundamentos de cibersegurança</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Módulo 3</p>
                    <div class="spacer"></div> 
                    <p>Introdução à programação aplicada à cibersegurança</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Módulo 4</p>
                    <div class="spacer"></div> 
                    <p>Hardware e redes de computadores</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Módulo 5</p>
                    <div class="spacer"></div> 
                    <p>Introdução às técnicas de análise de evidências</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Módulo 6</p>
                    <div class="spacer"></div> 
                    <p>Análise de vulnerabilidades – iniciação</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Módulo 7</p>
                    <div class="spacer"></div> 
                    <p>Cibersegurança ativa</p>
                </div>
                <div class="spacer-middle"></div>
                <div class="hours-text">
                    <p>= 320H</p>
                    <p>Duração da Formação</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And i made the css too, but the result was this:

[image]

Can some one help me with the css or html case needed, to make a exact copy of the first picture?

Thank you.

Comment: dont use empty divs to add a space. Thats what you have `margins` for or `gap` for `grid` and `flexbox`. If you want to add such pseudo-elements, use `::before` or `::after`

Comment: To me it loos like normal use of [CSS Columns](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/)